# AucTeX doesn't start properly

Tags: auctex, start-up

I just moved to an M2 Mac and simultaneously abandoned AquaMacs for Emacs 28.2. Everything more or less works, except that after installing AucTeX, it fails to start properly, giving me

```
   internal--fill-string-single-line("Use the command `TeX-Omega-mode' to change this va...")
   internal--fill-string-single-line("Use the command `TeX-Omega-mode' to change this va...")
   internal--fill-string-single-line("Use the command `TeX-Omega-mode' to change this va...")
   internal--format-docstring-line("Use the command `%s' to change this variable." TeX-Omega-mode)
   #f(compiled-function (arg1 arg2 &rest rest) "Define a new minor mode MODE.\nThis defines the toggle command MODE and (by default) a control variable\nMODE (you can override this with the :variable keyword, see below).\nDOC is the documentation for the mode toggle command.\n\nThe defined mode command takes one optional (prefix) argument.\nInteractively with no prefix argument, it toggles the mode.\nA prefix argument enables the mode if the argument is positive,\nand disables it otherwise.\n\nWhen called from Lisp, the mode command toggles the mode if the\nargument is `toggle', disables the mode if the argument is a\nnon-positive integer, and enables the mode otherwise (including\nif the argument is omitted or nil or a positive integer).\n\nIf DOC is nil, give the mode command a basic doc-string\ndocumenting what its argument does.  If the word \"ARG\" does not\nappear in DOC, a paragraph is added to DOC explaining\nusage of the mode argument.\n\nBODY contains code to execute each time the mode is enabled or disabled.\n  It is executed after toggling the mode, and before running MODE-hook.\n  Before the actual body code, you can write keyword arguments, i.e.\n  alternating keywords and values.  If you provide BODY, then you must\n  provide at least one keyword argument (e.g. `:lighter nil`).\n  The following special keywords are supported (other keywords are passed\n  to `defcustom' if the minor mode is global):\n\n:global GLOBAL\11If non-nil specifies that the minor mode is not meant to be\n\11\11buffer-local, so don't make the variable MODE buffer-local.\n\11\11By default, the mode is buffer-local.\n:init-value VAL\11the initial value of the mode's variable.\n\11\11Note that the minor mode function won't be called by setting\n\11\11this option, so the value *reflects* the minor mode's natural\n\11\11initial state, rather than *setting* it.\n\11\11In the vast majority of cases it should be nil.\n\11\11Not used if you also specify :variable.\n:lighter SPEC\11Text displayed in the mode line when the mode is on.\n:keymap MAP\11Keymap bound to the mode keymap.  Defaults to `MODE-map'.\n                If non-nil, it should be an unquoted variable name (whose value\n                is a keymap), or an expression that returns either a keymap or\n\11\11a list of (KEY . BINDING) pairs where KEY and BINDING are\n\11\11suitable for `define-key'.  If you supply a KEYMAP argument\n\11\11that is not a symbol, this macro defines the variable MODE-map\n\11\11and gives it the value that KEYMAP specifies.\n:interactive VAL  Whether this mode should be a command or not.  The default\n                is to make it one; use nil to avoid that.  If VAL is a list,\n                it's interpreted as a list of major modes this minor mode\n                is useful in.\n:variable PLACE\11The location to use instead of the variable MODE to store\n\11\11the state of the mode.\11This can be simply a different\n\11\11named variable, or a generalized variable.\n\11\11PLACE can also be of the form (GET . SET), where GET is\n\11\11an expression that returns the current state, and SET is\n\11\11a function that takes one argument, the new state, which should\n                be assigned to PLACE.  If you specify a :variable, this function\n                does not define a MODE variable (nor any of the terms used\n\11\11in :variable).\n:after-hook     A single Lisp form which is evaluated after the mode hooks\n                have been run.  It should not be quoted.\n\nFor example, you could write\n  (define-minor-mode foo-mode \"If enabled, foo on you!\"\n    :lighter \" Foo\" :require \\='foo :global t :group \\='hassle :version \"27.5\"\n    ...BODY CODE...)\n\nFor backward compatibility with the Emacs<21 calling convention,\nthe keywords can also be preceded by the obsolete triplet\nINIT-VALUE LIGHTER KEYMAP." #<bytecode 0x1bb50d2338ff34ff>)(TeX-Omega-mode "Minor mode for using the Omega engine." :init-value nil :lighter nil :keymap nil :group 'TeX-command (TeX-engine-set (if TeX-Omega-mode 'omega 'default)))
   (define-minor-mode TeX-Omega-mode "Minor mode for using the Omega engine." :init-value nil :lighter nil :keymap nil :group 'TeX-command (TeX-engine-set (if TeX-Omega-mode 'omega 'default)))
   eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.0/tex.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 69136
   load-with-code-conversion("/Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.0/tex.el" "/Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.0/tex.el" nil t)
   TeX-tex-mode()
   apply(TeX-tex-mode nil)
   tex-mode()
   set-auto-mode-0(tex-mode nil)
   set-auto-mode--apply-alist((("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode) ("\\.mjs\\'" . javascript-mode) ("\\.hva\\'" . latex-mode) ("\\.d[i]?\\'" . d-mode) ("\\.gpg\\(~\\|\\.~[0-9]+~\\)?\\'" nil epa-file) ("\\.elc\\'" . elisp-byte-code-mode) ("\\.zst\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.dz\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.xz\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.lzma\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.lz\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.g?z\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.bz2\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.Z\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.vr[hi]?\\'" . vera-mode) ("\\(?:\\.\\(?:rbw?\\|ru\\|rake\\|thor\\|jbuilder\\|rabl\\|ge..." . ruby-mode) ("\\.re?st\\'" . rst-mode) ("\\.py[iw]?\\'" . python-mode) ("\\.m\\'" . octave-maybe-mode) ("\\.less\\'" . less-css-mode) ("\\.scss\\'" . scss-mode) ("\\.awk\\'" . awk-mode) ("\\.\\(u?lpc\\|pike\\|pmod\\(\\.in\\)?\\)\\'" . pike-mode) ("\\.idl\\'" . idl-mode) ("\\.java\\'" . java-mode) ("\\.m\\'" . objc-mode) ("\\.ii\\'" . c++-mode) ("\\.i\\'" . c-mode) ("\\.lex\\'" . c-mode) ("\\.y\\(acc\\)?\\'" . c-mode) ("\\.h\\'" . c-or-c++-mode) ("\\.c\\'" . c-mode) ("\\.\\(CC?\\|HH?\\)\\'" . c++-mode) ("\\.[ch]\\(pp\\|xx\\|\\+\\+\\)\\'" . c++-mode) ("\\.\\(cc\\|hh\\)\\'" . c++-mode) ("\\.\\(bat\\|cmd\\)\\'" . bat-mode) ("\\.[sx]?html?\\(\\.[a-zA-Z_]+\\)?\\'" . mhtml-mode) ("\\.svgz?\\'" . image-mode) ("\\.svgz?\\'" . xml-mode) ("\\.x[bp]m\\'" . image-mode) ("\\.x[bp]m\\'" . c-mode) ("\\.p[bpgn]m\\'" . image-mode) ("\\.tiff?\\'" . image-mode) ("\\.gif\\'" . image-mode) ("\\.png\\'" . image-mode) ("\\.jpe?g\\'" . image-mode) ("\\.te?xt\\'" . text-mode) ("\\.[tT]e[xX]\\'" . tex-mode) ("\\.ins\\'" . tex-mode) ("\\.ltx\\'" . latex-mode) ...) nil nil)
   set-auto-mode()
   normal-mode(t)
   after-find-file(nil t)
   find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer lucy.tex> "~/lucy.tex" nil nil "~/lucy.tex" (5719465 16777233))
   find-file-noselect("/Users/rlipsett/lucy.tex")
   #f(compiled-function (displayable-buffers dir line column name) #<bytecode 0x1e47bdbe1b883184>)((nil) "~/.emacs.d/" (0) (0) "/Users/rlipsett/lucy.tex")
   command-line-1(("--execute" "(server-start)" "/Users/rlipsett/lucy.tex"))
   command-line()
   normal-top-level()
```

and it then exhausts stack with calls to `fill-string-single-line`. I'm not really a LISP developer or an Emacs wizard, just an Emacs/AucTeX user. Can anyone help me figure out what is going on? Emacs and emacsclient were both installed using HomeBrew, if that matters.

Additional information:

1. The code near position 69136 looks like this:

```
(define-minor-mode TeX-Omega-mode
  "Minor mode for using the Omega engine."
  :init-value nil :lighter nil :keymap nil
  :group 'TeX-command
  (TeX-engine-set (if TeX-Omega-mode 'omega 'default)))
(defalias 'tex-omega-mode #'TeX-Omega-mode)
(make-obsolete 'TeX-Omega-mode #'TeX-engine-set "11.86")
(make-obsolete-variable 'TeX-Omega-mode 'TeX-engine "11.86")
```

2. Doing `M-x load-file` on the `tex.el` file gives the same error as above; if run with `emacs -q`, it gives the error: `Cannot open load-file: No such file or directory, tex-site`.
3. `emacs --debug-init` starts properly, but then loading a tex file produces the same error as above.

Addendum 2: Reinstalling AucTeX gives

```
Compiling internal form(s) at Thu Jul 20 16:40:37 2023
Leaving directory ‘/Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1’

Compiling file /Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1/auctex.el at Thu Jul 20 16:40:37 2023
Entering directory ‘/Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1/’

Compiling file /Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1/bib-cite.el at Thu Jul 20 16:40:37 2023
bib-cite.el:590:1: Error: Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’

Compiling file /Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1/context-en.el at Thu Jul 20 16:40:37 2023
context-en.el:33:1: Error: Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’
```

followed by a long collection of similar errors on various `el` files.

Addendum 3: Setting `debug-on-signal` and `debug-on-error`, then byte compiling `tex.el`, produces the following stack trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable ansi-color-faces-vector)
  default-toplevel-value(ansi-color-faces-vector)
  custom-initialize-reset(ansi-color-faces-vector (funcall #'#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1ca1c2cd84e54>)))
  custom-declare-variable(ansi-color-faces-vector (funcall #'#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1ca1c2cd84e54>)) "Faces used for SGR control sequences determining a..." :type (vector face face face face face face face face) :group ansi-colors)
  byte-code("\300\301\302\303\304\305\306\307&\7\210\310\311\312\313\306\301\304\314&\7\210\310\315\316\317\306\301\304\314&\7\210\310\320\321\322\306\301\304\314&\7\210\310\323\324\325\306\301..." [custom-declare-group ansi-colors nil "Translating SGR control sequences to faces.\nThis t..." :version "21.1" :group processes custom-declare-face ansi-color-bold ((t :inherit 'bold)) "Face used to render bold text." "28.1" ansi-color-faint ((t :weight light)) "Face used to render faint text." ansi-color-italic ((t :inherit 'italic)) "Face used to render italic text." ansi-color-underline ((t :inherit 'underline)) "Face used to render underlined text." ansi-color-slow-blink ((t :box (:line-width -1))) "Face used to render slowly blinking text." ansi-color-fast-blink ((t :box (:line-width -1))) "Face used to render rapidly blinking text." ansi-color-inverse ((t :inverse-video t)) "Face used to render inverted video text." ansi-color-black ((t :foreground "black" :background "black")) "Face used to render black color code." ansi-color-red ((t :foreground "red3" :background "red3")) "Face used to render red color code." ansi-color-green ((t :foreground "green3" :background "green3")) "Face used to render green color code." ansi-color-yellow ((t :foreground "yellow3" :background "yellow3")) "Face used to render yellow color code." ansi-color-blue ((t :foreground "blue2" :background "blue2")) "Face used to render blue color code." ansi-color-magenta ((t :foreground "magenta3" :background "magenta3")) "Face used to render magenta color code." ansi-color-cyan ...] 10)
  require(ansi-color)
  byte-code("\300\301!\210\300\302!\210\300\303!\210\304\305\306\307\310\311%\210\304\312\306\313\310\305%\207" [require ring ansi-color regexp-opt custom-declare-group comint nil "General command interpreter in a window stuff." :group processes comint-completion "Completion facilities in comint."] 6)
  require(comint)
  byte-code("\300\301!\210\300\302!\210\300\303!\210\304\305\306\307\310\311\310\312&\7\210\313\314\315\316\317DD\320\321\322%\210\313\323\315\316\324DD\325\321\322%\210\313\326\315..." [require tool-bar comint text-property-search custom-declare-group compilation nil "Run compiler as inferior of Emacs, parse error mes..." :group tools processes custom-declare-variable compilation-mode-hook funcall function #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f400016fe914>) "List of hook functions run by `compilation-mode'." :type hook compilation-start-hook #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f400016fe914>) "Hook run after starting a new compilation process...." compilation-window-height #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f400016fe914>) "Number of lines in a compilation window.\nIf nil, u..." (choice (const :tag "Default" nil) integer) compilation-transform-file-match-alist #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f400016fe914>) "Alist of regexp/replacements to alter file names i..." (repeat (list regexp (choice (const :tag "No replacement" nil) string))) :version "27.1"] 8)
  compilation-mode()
  emacs-lisp-compilation-mode()
  byte-compile-log-file()
  byte-compile-from-buffer(#<buffer  *Compiler Input*>)
  byte-compile-file("~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1/tex.el" nil)
  funcall-interactively(byte-compile-file "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1/tex.el" nil)
  call-interactively(byte-compile-file record nil)
  command-execute(byte-compile-file record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "byte-compile-file" "byte-com")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "byte-compile-file" "byte-com")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: This looks really weird to me: I tried `M-x load-file` on the `tex.el` file in my setup and I cannot reproduce the problem, but I also checked out the file around the reported position of the error and cannot see anything strange in my case. Can you see if you have something strange around buffer position 69136 of `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.0/tex.el`? And maybe try loading that file by hand with `M-x load-file` in an `emacs -q` session and see if you get the same error. You can also try `emacs --debug-init`.

Comment: @NickD See additional information above.

Comment: OK - thanks! So the code looks normal. What happens if you cut-and-paste the `(define-minor-mode ...)` form into your *scratch* buffer and evaluate that?  Press `C-j` after the last closing paren of the form. If that fails, there are two possibilities: something wrong with AucTex or something wrong with `define-minor-mode`. There is an example minor mode in the [Elisp Reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html): try copying the definition in your `*scratch*` buffer and evaluating it...

Comment: If that still gives the error, AucTeX is absolved; otherwise try reinstalling AucTex. If AucTeX is not at fault... I guess we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: @NickD That succeeded and printed `TeX-Omega-mode` in the scratch buffer following the code. Reinstalling AucTeX produced the new collection of error messages on compilation, shown above.

Comment: Try compiling one of these `.el` files by hand: open, say, `/Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1/auctex.el` and do `M-x byte-compile-file`. Make sure that you have `debug-on-error` turned on and post the backtrace.

Comment: `auctex.el` compiled without error, but `tex.el` gave an error at line 1604 (the same place as before). Running `emacs --debug-init` and setting `debug-on-error` to `t`, all I got was
Compiling file /Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1/tex.el at Fri Jul 21 09:14:12 2023
Entering directory ‘/Users/rlipsett/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.2.1/’
tex.el:1604:1: Error: Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’`
Doesn't look like it entered the debugger; am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry - I now see that `auctex.el` compiled without error: things started going awry with `bib-cite.el`. What error did you get when byte-compiling `tex.el` with `M-x byte-compile`?   I don't quite understand what you did for the debug stuff.

Comment: Maybe we can continue the discussion in a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147373/rogerl-nickd).